# How to make Drag element always on the top?

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qml, qtquick2, qt6

This is the [Qt Drag and Drop Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-draganddrop-example.html).

[image: 43afccd0-7442-4aff-a706-1e1d5ca2d254-image.png]

As you can see here, the 5th tile is under the 6th tile, and the 5th tile can be above of 4th tile.

[image]

But I want the dragging element to be always above of all the elements.

I've tried setting `z` of `Rectangle` in `MouseArea` to `1` or larger, but it didn't work.

Comment: Check the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981404/qml-drag-and-drop-free-positioning/30991733#30991733) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @folibis's help in comment, here is the answer for my quesiont.
For anyone who has the same problem as me, you just need to specify a larger `z` for `delegate` whose `drag.active` of `MouseArea` is `true`.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true
    color: "#1F1F1F"
    Column {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Repeater {
            model: 2
            delegate: Rectangle {
                z: mouseArea.drag.active ? 2 : 0 // key
                color: "#aaaaaa"
                width: 300
                height: 50

                MouseArea {
                    id: mouseArea
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    drag.target: rec

                    Rectangle {
                        id: rec
                        color: "white"
                        height: parent.height / 2
                        width: parent.width / 2
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                        Text {
                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                            text: "test " + index
                            color: "black"
                        }
                        states: [
                            State {
                                when: mouseArea.drag.active
                                AnchorChanges {
                                    target: rec
                                    anchors.verticalCenter: undefined
                                    anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of running the above code：

[image]