# How to make MouseArea in Loader take effect?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm writting a draggable control. This is my minimal reproductive example. My issue is, the hover, click events of `Loader` and `MouseArea` cannot take effect at the same time. If I set a bigger `z` for either of them, the other will have no effect.

```
Window {
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true
    color: "#181818"
    Component {
        id: dele
        Rectangle {
            color: "#1f1f1f"

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "hello"
                color: "#cccccc"
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onClicked: console.log(123)
            }
        }
    }

    Loader {
        id: dragTarget
        width: 200
        height: 200
        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            left: parent.left
        }

        sourceComponent: dele
        Drag.active: mouseArea.drag.active
        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            drag.target: dragTarget
            onContainsMouseChanged: {
                console.log(1234)
            }
        }
        states: [
            State {
                when: mouseArea.drag.active
                AnchorChanges {
                    target: dragTarget
                    anchors {
                        left: undefined
                        top: undefined
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

EDIT: I simplified my question. My current problem is that the `MouseArea` in `Loader` and the `MouseArea` in `sourceComponent` cannot take effect at the same time.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here

Comment: @folibis I'm trying to writing a draggable control, and I wanted to keep a same control in place when I drag it, so I used two `Loader`s. Besides, in order to implement drag, I placed a `MouseArea` in the latter `Loader`. But when I run the code, the `MouseArea` from `sourceComponent` and the `MouseArea` used to implement the drag do not work at the same time

Comment: sorry for that, but neither the idea nor the implementation attempt are absolutely unclear here. why using Loaders. too many MouseAreas. Do you want 2 draggable items to be displayed in front of the others when dragging? If yes check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981404/qml-drag-and-drop-free-positioning/30991733#30991733) answer.

Comment: I simplified my example. The reason I use `Loader` here is that this is a reusable control so that users are able to  specify its `sourceComponent`. The `MouseArea` in `dele` is provided by user, while the `MouseArea` in `Loader` is used to implement drag.